# mongo script ReferenceError: Chance is not defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

What is wrong with my code?

I am invoking js script with `mongo script.js` command. And load is mongo way that allows include another js script. https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/load/

I am getting `mongo script  ReferenceError: Chance is not defined` after execute code below. Numeral.js lib works.

```
load("../assets/node_modules/numeral/numeral.js");
load("../assets/node_modules/chance/chance.js");

var db = new Mongo().getDB("testdb1");
var col = db.getCollectionNames();

var chance = new Chance(45);
//or
Chance(45);
//or 
chance.something();
```

Comment: Why do you use load() function instead of require()?

Comment: I am invoking js script with `mongo script.js` command. And load is mongo way that allows include another js script. https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not support CommonJS properly yet. That's why Chance does not work inside Mongo script shell. It happens to work for numeral since it defines numeral() function as a top level function.